# Issue while executing test case on chrome using selenium 3.6.0

Tags: automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, selenium3

I am using selenium 3.6.0 server and when I try to execute test case on chrome it stops after below statement. Chrome version am using is 61 and chrome driver is 2.33

> Oct 26, 2017 2:34:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake >createSession
>   INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the >remote end

Comment: Please post the full stack trace.

Comment: I didnt get any exception, but this is the below log and test execution hangs for a long time
Oct 26, 2017 2:34:50 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Oct 26, 2017 2:44:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.

Comment: This is not an error message. It's logging information which can be disabled.

Comment: Please post your code snippet in formatted manner with the stack trace. Your remote session is not getting created.